# Excel Cells auto filled with value numbers

Tags: excel, vba

What I want in MS Excel 2010 is, when i enter number “15” in the value box, fifteen cells should be automatically  filled with yellow color as shown in below link example image. If I enter the number ”5” than five cells should be auto filled. Is there any possibility? Please guide. Really appreciate your help.

http://www.thewebmakerz.com/Sample/excel-help.gif

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Excel's **conditional formatting** feature:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, I have tried it and its working. I have one more query if a cell is already filled with color can this formula be modified accordingly to skip the filled cell and pick only the empty cell? is it possible?